# SQL Server Procedure Parameter List

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, procedure

I'm using .Net SqlParameter, but I'd like send to my procedure a list of terms to search. For example

My list would be like that:

```
 Title   |  Value
'Women'  | 'Chain'
'Little' | 'Boy'
```

I need for each terms include a row like this:

```
AND (field.Name = @title AND contains(fv.Value, @value))
AND (field.Name = 'Women' AND contains(fv.Value, '"Chain"'))
AND (field.Name = 'Little' AND contains(fv.Value, '"Boy"'))
```

How can I perform this?

Comment: read about TableValued parameters

Comment: you can also use xml parameters https://www.simple-talk.com/blogs/2012/01/05/using-xml-to-pass-lists-as-parameters-in-sql-server/